# Replicate react-router v3 onEnter nextState argument to react-router-dom v4

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-dom

Is there a way to replicate `nextState` argument in `react-router v3` to `react-router-dom v4`? I'm trying to get the id through `params`, have not been able to fine a suitable way to make this work:

Want to migrate `react-router v3`

```
const onEnterAuthPage = (nextState) => {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    browserHistory.replace('/');
  } else {
    Session.set('selectedNoteId', nextState.params.id);
  }
};

export const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Login} onEnter={onEnterPublicPage}/>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} onEnter={onEnterPublicPage}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard/:id" component={Dashboard} onEnter={onEnterAuthPage}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
  </Router>
);
```

To `react-router-dom v4`

```
const onEnterAuthPage = () => {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    browserHistory.replace("/");
  } else {
    //want to call params argument here with session
  }
};

export const routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => {
          onEnterPublicPage();
          return <Login />;
        }}
      />
      <Route
        path="/signup"
        render={() => {
          onEnterPublicPage();
          return <Signup />;
        }}
      />
      <Route
        path="/dashboard/:id"
        render={() => {
          onEnterAuthPage();
          return <Dashboard />;
        }}
      />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);
```

I've been trying to find a work around this, will be happy to find a solution.